# I accidentally broke my charging port of my laptop and its not turning on anymore. Is this serious?

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, lenovo-laptop, charging

I accidentally broke my charging port of my laptop. The plastic in the middle of the port that holds the non-insulated cables inside the port just fell off so the cables were free to touch. My laptop was turned on at the moment but after the accident was dead and never alive again. My theory is that the cables touched each other and generated a short circuit. My Laptop didn't fell down. I peeked inside the laptop and all the internals seems fine. No broken cables or anything, just the port.

My question is: Is there a protection for this kind of accidents or the entire motherboard is dead?

Laptop name if needed: Lenovo IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming (i5 9 generation and GTX 1650)

This is the port type. Can't put images but you can search on google "square laptop charging port"

Comment: Take it to a repair shop. We can't tell without a proper diagnosis.

Comment: “My question is: Is there a protection for this kind of accidents or the entire motherboard is dead?” - The protection was the middle of the port.

Comment: You definitely should take it to a authorized repair shop. Because the laptop is not booting, it definitely can be serious, and there may be some irreparable damage, which may not be visible. Some parts may be needed to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there a protection for this kind of accidents ...**

There is very little protection against short-circuits caused by physical damage.

> **or the entire motherboard is dead?**

This is unlikely. It is possible that there is extensive damage but it is more likely that the damage is localised. In your case it *might* just be the power management sections that are damaged. However fixing even local damage to tiny surface-mount components often requires specialised equipment and skills. Unless you are very proficient in electronics faultfinding and SMD soldering, you should leave this to a professional.